# How to pass configuration from spark-submit to yarn cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, spark-submit

I'm wondering is there any way for spark-submit to temporarily change yarn job's configuration?

The question is because our Spark over yarn cluster's history server only allows admin to access, which is not convenience for user to retrieve their own job's log. I learned "`mapreduce.job.acl-view-job`" in mapreduce-default.xml can changes specific job's ACL. As I'm using `spark-submit` to launch job, and "--conf" is reserved for spark itself's, but how can I set yarn's configuration from command line along with application?

Answer (score 2):

You can modify Spark's Hadoop Configuration (obtained via `SparkContaxt.hadoopConfiguration`) by adding a `--conf` with a `spark.hadoop.` prefixed.

In you example it would be

```
spark-submit --conf spark.hadoop.mapreduce.job.acl-view-job=YOUR_ACL_STATEMENT ...
```